# How do I prioritize a radio selection across multiple questions using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to teach myself how to make a game where based on my selection I get a link to another page (but not send a form - I'm trying to make this show up on the same page). In this scenario I have three questions and what I'd like to do is have Link 1 show up if ANY of the questions are marked yes. Right now, if I select yes, yes, no, Link 2 shows up.

Also, is there a way to send the values to the function but have it only trigger the divs after the last selection is made? Something like a submit button that works onclick I guess. If I go that route, how do I send the values of the radio buttons to the function?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('link1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('link2').style.display = 'none';
};
function showdiv(x)
{
    if (x==1){
    document.getElementById('link1').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('link2').style.display='none';
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('link1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('link2').style.display='block';
    }
    return;
}
```

```html
<body>
<label>Do you need equipment?</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="showdiv(1)" name="q1">Yes
<input type="radio" onclick="showdiv(0)" name="q1">No

</br>
<label>Do you need food?</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="showdiv(1)" name="q2">Yes
<input type="radio" onclick="showdiv(0)" name="q2">No

</br>
<label>Do you need help?</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="showdiv(1)" name="q3">Yes
<input type="radio" onclick="showdiv(0)" name="q3">No
</br>

<div id="link1">
Show Link 1
</div>
<div id="link2">
Show Link 2
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the function triggers every time an answer is clicked. When you select "No" on question 3, the variable x equals 0, so the function does it's job and hides link 1 and shows link 2.

If you would like to use a button to submit the answer, your code would look like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('link1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('link2').style.display = 'none';
};
var x, y, z;
function a1(answer1){
x = answer1;
console.log(x);
};
function a2(answer2){
y = answer2;
console.log(y);
};
function a3(answer3){
z = answer3;
console.log(z);
};
function showdiv()
{
    if (x==1 | y==1 | z==1){
    console.log("One of the questions is 1");
    document.getElementById('link1').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('link2').style.display='none';
    }
    else {
    console.log("None of the questions is 1");
    document.getElementById('link1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('link2').style.display='block';
    }
    return;
}
```

```html
<body>
<label>Do you need equipment?</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="a1(1)" name="q1">Yes
<input type="radio" onclick="a1(0)" name="q1">No

</br>
<label>Do you need food?</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="a2(1)" name="q2">Yes
<input type="radio" onclick="a2(0)" name="q2">No

</br>
<label>Do you need help?</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="a3(1)" name="q3">Yes
<input type="radio" onclick="a3(0)" name="q3">No
</br>
<button onclick="showdiv()">Submit</button>

<div id="link1">
Show Link 1
</div>
<div id="link2">
Show Link 2
</div>

</body>
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. Your explanation and the code you provided really helped me understand. I read somewhere that clean simple code is the way to go and I think I misunderstood it by having one function trying to do everything. Your code makes more sense. Thanks again!